# how to merge dataframe based on two columns without order of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running into the following issue. I want to merge two data frames on multiple columns. Example data frames are as follows: df1:

```
df1:
playerA   playerB  Weight
kim         lee      1
jackson     kim      3
dan         lee      4


df2:
name1   name2      score
dan         lee      11
dan         kim      23
jackson     kim      44
lee         kim      35
Jackson     lee      26
lee         dan      27
```

I want to merge this two dataframe based on two columns.
`df1[['playerA','playerB']],df2[['name1','name2']]`

But the problem is, I want to merge this two data frame without considering the order of columns.

I tried

`result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on =df1[['playerA','playerB']],df2[['name1','name2']])`

But it didn't work.

Here is what I Want,

```
df1:
playerA   playerB  Weight score
kim         lee      1    
jackson     kim      3
dan         lee      4

I want to merge df1 and df2 by using two columns from each data frame without considering the order 
(df1[['playerA','playerB']],df2[['name1','name2']])

df2_merge:
name1   name2      score  weight
dan         lee      11    4
kim         lee      23    1
jackson     kim      44    3
lee         kim      35    1
kim        jacson     26   3
lee         dan      27    4

And then I want to delete the row which has the same name list.

Thus, here is my final wishes

df2_merge_ final:
name1   name2      score  weight
dan         lee      11    4
kim         lee      23    1
jackson     kim      44    3
```

I am not sure what else to try. Any advice? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new columns filled by sorted values and then use `merge` with remove unnecessary columns:

```
df1[['a','b']] = np.sort(df1[['playerA','playerB']], axis=1)
df2[['a','b']] = np.sort(df2[['name1','name2']], axis=1)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b']).drop(['a','b','name1','name2'], axis=1)
print (result)
   playerA playerB  Weight  score
0      kim     lee       1     35
1  jackson     kim       3     44
2      dan     lee       4     11
3      dan     lee       4     27
```

---

If need first unique combination add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1[['a','b']] = np.sort(df1[['playerA','playerB']], axis=1)
df2[['a','b']] = np.sort(df2[['name1','name2']], axis=1)

df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['a','b'])

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b']).drop(['a','b','name1','name2'], axis=1)
print (result)
   playerA playerB  Weight  score
0      kim     lee       1     35
1  jackson     kim       3     44
2      dan     lee       4     11
```